# Java : UnsupportedOperationException : ASM8 and ASM9 required

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, glassfish

1. Spring boot application 3.0. Hello world application
2. war created
3. Deploying on Glassfish 7
4. Open JDK 17

This is an exception which is being received from glassfish server logs.

> Exception while visiting org/springframework/aot/hint/predicate/ResourceHintsPredicates$AggregatedResourcePatternHints.class of size 3983
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Record requires ASM8
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponent(ClassVisitor.java:323)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:953)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:731)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:137)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:100)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitPermittedSubclass(ClassVisitor.java:281)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:706)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:137)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:100)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--            <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "myName", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
}
```

Comment: And you nowhere indicate what you are trying to achieve? Looks like you are trying to use AOT but not sure. You are mentioning no versions and no setup you are using. Basically you are dumping a stacktrace and expect us to magically know what is wrong. It looks however if you are using JDK17 with a glassfish version that isn't compatible with it. Why use glassfish at all if you are using Spring Boot?

Comment: Information updated.
Need to deploy on glassfish. 
Versions are compatible already checked.

Comment: Judging from the error you get the versions aren't compatible else you wouldn't get the error. Judging from the stacktrace it includes an older ASM version which isn't JDK17 compatible and thus makes glassfish not (fully) jdk17 compatible.